# concatenating 2 df including all index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dfs:

```
df1
           ponder     valor     
X         0.977011   145.000        
X         0.833333  -421.660    
Y         0.649425   1408.500          
W         0.609195   560.500         
Z         0.471264   132.300         
Y         0.431034 -1439.250          
X         0.321839   435.116 

df2
     sub_0
B     10
X     12  
C     16
Z     9
```

I would like to generate a new df that join the values that match to the corresponding axis and add the values from `df2` that dont exist in `df1` in this case : `B` and `C`.

In short the desired output would look like this:

```
           ponder     valor     sub_0
X         0.977011   145.000      12  
X         0.833333  -421.660      12
Y         0.649425   1408.500     Nan     
W         0.609195   560.500      Nan   
Z         0.471264   132.300      9  
Y         0.431034 -1439.250      Nan    
X         0.321839   435.116      12
B           Nan         Nan       10       
C           Nan         Nan       16
```

The problem with the `join` function is that it only remain the index values from the first df stated in the join function:

```
  sub_0   ponder    valor    
B   10    NaN      NaN
Z   9   0.609195  560.500
C   16    NaN      NaN
X   12  0.977011  145.000
X   12  0.321839  435.116
X   12  0.833333 -421.660
```

How could I obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform an outer merge on the indices:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

     ponder     valor  sub_0
B       NaN       NaN   10.0
C       NaN       NaN   16.0
W  0.609195   560.500    NaN
X  0.977011   145.000   12.0
X  0.833333  -421.660   12.0
X  0.321839   435.116   12.0
Y  0.649425  1408.500    NaN
Y  0.431034 -1439.250    NaN
Z  0.471264   132.300    9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If the order is matter , you should using merge, if not , you can using `combine_first`

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[273]: 
     ponder  sub_0     valor
B       NaN   10.0       NaN
C       NaN   16.0       NaN
W  0.609195    NaN   560.500
X  0.977011   12.0   145.000
X  0.833333   12.0  -421.660
X  0.321839   12.0   435.116
Y  0.649425    NaN  1408.500
Y  0.431034    NaN -1439.250
Z  0.471264    9.0   132.300
```

Or

```
df1.join(df2,how='outer')
Out[282]: 
     ponder     valor  sub_0
B       NaN       NaN   10.0
C       NaN       NaN   16.0
W  0.609195   560.500    NaN
X  0.977011   145.000   12.0
X  0.833333  -421.660   12.0
X  0.321839   435.116   12.0
Y  0.649425  1408.500    NaN
Y  0.431034 -1439.250    NaN
Z  0.471264   132.300    9.0
```